# Pass Outlook variable data to API

Tags: vba, api, http-post

API constants for example `sendDataToApi = "mail_from=mail@mail.com&mail_to=mail@mail.com` work. API receive data.

VBA code for connection with API:

```
Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

URL = "https://url.xdomain.com/api/insert"

objHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

sendDataToApi = "mail_from=mail@mail.com&mail_to=&mail2@mail.com"
    
objHTTP.Send sendDataToApi
```

What is the syntax for inserting variables to be sent?

For example `strTo = objMail.To` and add to `sendDataApi`.

This part of code adds me to API strTo instead of email.

```
sendDataToApi = "mail_from=strTo"
```

Comment: `sendDataToApi = "mail_from=mail@mail.com&mail_to=" & strTo`